# How to update UI Elements from UDP listening response in Kotlin Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I am currently trying to make a mobile app that displays a specific UDP message response after listening process, but for some reason the UI doesn't update from the dummy data I provided. Below are what I've tried to code:

//UDPReceiverApp, = MainActivity code snippet

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import com.example.udpbroadcastreceiver.ui.theme.UDPBroadcastReceiverTheme

class UDPReceiverApp : ComponentActivity() {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var udpReceiverService: UDPReceiverService

        private val receivedDataState = mutableStateOf("No data received")

        fun uiUpdate(data: String) {
            receivedDataState.value = data // Update the Composable with received data
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

//        val viewModel = viewModel<UDPReceiverViewModel>()
        udpReceiverService = UDPReceiverService()
        startService(Intent(this, udpReceiverService::class.java))

        setContent {
            UDPBroadcastReceiverTheme {
                // Call the Composable function for the user interface
                UDPReceiverScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//UDPReceiverScreen, UI composable

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicTextField
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.udpbroadcastreceiver.ui.theme.UDPBroadcastReceiverTheme

@Composable
fun UDPReceiverScreen(viewModel: UDPReceiverViewModel = viewModel()) {
    Column {
        BasicTextField(
            value = viewModel.receivedData,
            onValueChange = {},
            singleLine = true,
            readOnly = true
        )
    }
}
```

//UDPReceiverService, code snippet that handles the UDP Listening and respond receiving process

```
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager
import java.net.DatagramPacket
import java.net.DatagramSocket

class UDPReceiverService : Service() {

    private val udpPort = 1111 //sample port number
    private lateinit var socket: DatagramSocket
    private lateinit var udpJob: Job
    private lateinit var wifiLock: WifiManager.WifiLock

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val viewModel = UDPReceiverViewModel()

        val wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        wifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_LOW_LATENCY, "MyWifiLock")
        wifiLock.acquire()

        udpJob = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            try {
                socket = DatagramSocket(udpPort)
                val buffer = ByteArray(1024)

                while (true) {
                    val packet = DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.size)
                    Log.d("myListener", "In here 1")
                    socket.soTimeout = 20000
                    socket.receive(packet)
                    Log.d("myListener", "In here 2")
                    // Process the received data here
                    val messgBytes = packet.data.copyOf(packet.length)
                    val messgAsHex = bytesToHex(messgBytes)
                    //val receivedData = String(packet.data, 0, packet.length)

                    Log.d("myListener", "In here 3")
                    Log.d("myListener", "$messgAsHex")
                    // Update the Composable with the received data
                    viewModel.receivedData = messgAsHex
                    if(messgAsHex.isNotEmpty() || messgAsHex.isNotBlank() || messgAsHex!=null){
                        super.onDestroy()
                        if(wifiLock != null){
                           if (wifiLock.isHeld) {
                               wifiLock.release()
                               Log.d("myListener", "lock released")
                           }
                        }
                        if(!wifiLock.isHeld){
                            Log.d("myListener", "lock is currently released")
                        }
                        udpJob.cancel()
                        socket.close()
                        Log.d("myListener", "released")
                        break
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.d("MyListener", "$e")
                super.onDestroy()
                wifiLock.release()
                udpJob.cancel()
                socket.close()
                Log.d("myListener", "released")
            }
        }
    }

    }
}

fun bytesToHex(bytes: ByteArray): String{
    val hexString = StringBuilder()
    for (byte in bytes){
        hexString.append(String.format("%02x", byte))
    }
    return hexString.toString()
}
```

//UDPReceiverViewModel, the view model code snippet

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class UDPReceiverViewModel:ViewModel() {
    var receivedData by mutableStateOf("No Data Received")
}
```

I'm still learning about viewmodels and concurrency with coroutines. and truth be told they confused me, even with the android dev training ground. so I hope anyone could give me something easier to follow with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view model instance needs to be shared between renderer and receiver, but in setting up the renderer, you seem to be using the default value:

```
setContent {
    UDPBroadcastReceiverTheme {
       // Call the Composable function for the user interface
       UDPReceiverScreen()
                         ^ Reference to view model missing here.
```

P.S. (edit): The bigger problem seems to be sharing the model reference with the service, which apparently is instantiated via reflection. Do you really have to use a service here?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, as for your question, I am not so sure as I am fairly new to this and some concept is a bit lost to me, so I am only following a guide to implement this. Do you have any further suggestion on what I should do? or the proper example on how to do this?

Comment: Try without a service and use (e.g.) a Thread to get started.